# Django url with prefix - not working correctly

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.7 with Mezzanine.

URL of my pages has a prefix `www.example.com/example`

So I use:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/example'
```

It works for default pages like blog. Blog has set url `blog` and it goes to `/example/blog`. But if I create custom link (for example in admin), it does not work. It skip `/example` in URL and goes directly to `/`.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

I added FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME into TEMPLATE_ACCESSIBLE_SETTINGS in settings.py. So it is look like that now:

```
TEMPLATE_ACCESSIBLE_SETTINGS = ('FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME', 'ACCOUNTS_APPROVAL_REQUIRED', 'ACCOUNTS_VERIFICATION_REQUIRED', 'ADMIN_MENU_COLLAPSED', 'BITLY_ACCESS_TOKEN', 'BLOG_USE_FEATURED_IMAGE', 'COMMENTS_DISQUS_SHORTNAME', 'COMMENTS_NUM_LATEST', 'COMMENTS_DISQUS_API_PUBLIC_KEY', 'COMMENTS_DISQUS_API_SECRET_KEY', 'COMMENTS_USE_RATINGS', 'DEV_SERVER', 'FORMS_USE_HTML5', 'GRAPPELLI_INSTALLED', 'GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID', 'JQUERY_FILENAME', 'LOGIN_URL', 'LOGOUT_URL', 'SITE_TITLE', 'SITE_TAGLINE', 'USE_L10N')
```

Now is possible to extend the urls in patterns easily:

```
{{ settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME }}/rest/of/url
```

Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrote the pattern in urls.py?

something like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^example/$",HandlingClass.as_view(),name='example'),)
```

Comment: @karthikr It should be there instead of homepage? Or url "/$" should stay there also? HandlingClass should be some view?